# Filtering Google Map using Checkboxes or Form Submit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get my map to filter out by three different regions when a checkbox is clicked.

```
 <style>
 html, body {   font-family:
 Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; }
 #map {   width: 1400px;   height: 800px;   border: 1px solid black; }
 </style>
      <body>

     <div id="Filters" style="margin:5px;background:#f4f4f4;border:1px solid #888;padding:   5px 5px 5px 10px;">
          <label style="color:#555;font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" for="tags">Filter
 by:</label>
          <select id="tags" style="outline:none;"> 
              <option value="all">All</option>
              <option value="Western">Western</option> 
              <option value="Central">Central</option> 
              <option value="Eastern">Eastern</option> 
          </select>
     </div>
     <form action="#">   All PC: <input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="boxclick(this,'allpc')" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;   Western: <input type="checkbox" id="Western" onclick="boxclick(this,'western')" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;   Central: <input type="checkbox" id="Central" onclick="boxclick(this,'central')" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;   Eastern: <input type="checkbox" id="Eastern" onclick="boxclick(this,'eastern')" /><br /> </form>
     <div id="map"></div>   </body>


 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function HomeControl(controlDiv, map)
 {
     // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control   
     // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
     // from the edge of the map 
     controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
     // Set CSS for the control border
     var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');  
     controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
     controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
     controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';  
     controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';  
     controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center'; 
     controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';  
     controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
     // Set CSS for the control interior
     var controlText = document.createElement('DIV');
     controlText.style.fontFamily = Arial,sans-serif';  
     controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';  
     controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
     controlText.style.paddingRight = 4px';
     controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Reset HHS Map</b>';  
     controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
     // Setup the click event listeners
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI,
     'click', function() {
         var resetmap = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);
         map.setCenter(resetmap);
         map.setZoom(5);
      });
 }

 function EastOnly(eastDiv, map) {
     // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
     // Setting  padding to 5 px will offset the control
     // from the edge of the map 
     eastDiv.style.padding = '5px';
     // Set CSS for the control border   var eastUI =
     document.createElement('DIV');  
     eastUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
     eastUI.style.borderStyle ='solid';
     eastUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
     eastUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
     eastUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
     eastUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';  
     eastDiv.appendChild(eastUI);
     // Set CSS for the control interior
     var eastText = document.createElement('DIV');  
 eastText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';  
 eastText.style.fontSize = '12px';  
 eastText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';  
 eastText.style.paddingRight = '4px';  
 eastText.innerHTML = '<b>Eastern  Only</b>';  
 eastUI.appendChild(eastText);
 // Setup the click event listeners   
 // google.maps.event.addDomListener(eastUI, 'click', function() {   
 // var eastmap = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);  
 // map.setCenter(eastmap);
 // map.setZoom(5);
 // });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(eastUI,
 'click', function hideeastern() {
         for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
           if (markers[i].region == 'eastern') {
             alert('eastern');
             //markers[i].setVisible(false);
           }
         }

      });   }


 (function() {

   // Creating an array that will contain hhs icons
      var hhsIcons = [];
      hhsIcons['Eastern'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage('{!$Resource.markerE}'    );
      hhsIcons['Western'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage('{!$Resource.markerW}'   );
      hhsIcons['Central'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage('{!$Resource.markerC}'   );

   window.onload = function() {

     // Create object literal containing the properties of the map
     var options = {  
       zoom:5,  
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),  
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       mapTypeControl: false
     };

     // Create the map  
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
 options);

     var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
     var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
     homeControlDiv.index = 1;
     map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(homeControlDiv);

     var eastControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
     var eastControl = new EastOnly(eastControlDiv, map);
     eastControlDiv.index = 1;
     map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(eastControlDiv);


     var jsonData = {'jsonaccounts': 
     [
     <apex:repeat value="{!Accounts}" var="abc">
       {
         'lat': '{!abc.Latitude__c}',
         'lng': '{!abc.Longitude__c}',
         'hhs': '{!abc.HHS_Region__c}'
       },
     </apex:repeat>
     ]};


     var accountname = [];
     var pcnumber = [];
     var director = [];
     var vp = [];
     var division = [];
     var beds = [];

     //Add field data for each account into respective arrays
     <apex:repeat value="{!Accounts}" var="acc">
     accountname.push("{!acc.name}");
     pcnumber.push("{!acc.PC__c}");
     director.push("{!acc.hhs_director__r.name}");
     vp.push("{!acc.area_vp__r.name}");
     division.push("{!acc.HHS_Region__c}");
     beds.push("{!acc.Beds__c}");
     </apex:repeat>


     // Create a variable that will hold the InfoWindow object
     var infowindow;


     var markers = [];


     // Loop through the jsondata
     for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.jsonaccounts.length; i++) {

     var jsonaccounts = jsonData.jsonaccounts[i];

       // Create marker data
       var myMarkerData = {                   // collecting all custom data that you want to add
                 region : jsonaccounts.hhs,   // to the marker object within an array.
                 }   
       // Adding the markers
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(jsonaccounts.lat,
 jsonaccounts.lng), 
         map: map,
         icon: hhsIcons[jsonaccounts.hhs],
         data: myMarkerData
       });
       marker.region = jsonaccounts.hhs;      
       markers.push(marker);      
       alert(markers[i].region);


       // Wrap the event listener inside an anonymous function 
       // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
       (function(i, marker) {

        // Create the event listener. It now has access to the values of
        // i and marker as they were during its creation
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker,
 'click', function() {

           if (!infowindow) {
             infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           }

           // Set the content of the InfoWindow
           infowindow.setContent('<b>' + accountname[i] + '</b>' + 
                                 '<br/>PC#: ' + pcnumber[i] + 
                                 '<br/>Director: ' + director[i] + 
                                 '<br/>VP: ' + vp[i] + 
                                 '<br/>Division: ' + division[i] + 
                                 '<br/>Beds: ' + beds[i]);

           // Tie the InfoWindow to the marker 
           infowindow.open(map, marker);

         });

       })(i, marker);

     }
       }; })();


 marker.region = region;
 markers.push(marker); function
 hide(region) {
         for (var i=0; i<map.markers.length; i++) {
           if (map. markers[i].region == region) {
             map.markers[i].setVisible(false);
           }
         }

       document.getElementById(eastern+"box").checked
 = true;
     }      
     function boxclick(box,region) {
       if (box.checked) {
         show(region);
       } else {
         hide(region);
       }
     }


 </script>
```

Comment: Can you put your code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a few things to learn here. 1. Its very hard for others to know what your code is, you should reduce your code down to its specific problem. It is hard to read with so much there and it looks like you have copy-pasted the whole thing in here. You should read [how to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)